# "A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

Tags: methods, namespaces

I`m trying to create a simple menu, but it says that

> A namespace cannot contain members such as fields or methods.

I`m really new to programing and I dont understand what I should do do fix the problem?

```
using System;

namespace pilmeny.cs
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] menuOptions = new string[] { "Första\t", "Andra\t", "Tredje\t", "Avsluta\n"};
            int menuSelect = 0;

            while(true){
                Console.Clear();
                Console.CursorVisible = false;

                if (menuSelect == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("* " + menuOptions[0] + "<--");
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[1]);
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[2]);
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[3]);
                }
                else if (menuSelect == 1){
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[0]);
                    Console.WriteLine("* " + menuOptions[1] + "<--");
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[2]);
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[3]);
                }
                else if (menuSelect == 2){
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[0]);
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[1]);
                    Console.WriteLine("* " + menuOptions[2] + "<--");
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[3]);
                }
                else if (menuSelect == 3){
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[0]);
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[1]);
                    Console.WriteLine(menuOptions[2]);
                    Console.WriteLine("* " + menuOptions[3] + "<--");
                }
                var keyPressed = Console.ReadKey();

                if (keyPressed.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow && menuSelect != menuOptions.Length - 1)
                {
                    menuSelect++;
                }
                else if (keyPressed.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow && menuSelect >= 1){
                    menuSelect--;
                }
                else if (keyPressed.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter){
                    switch (menuSelect){
                        case 0:
                            FirstChoice();
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            SecondChoice();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            ThirdChoice();
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            FourthChoice();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void FirstChoice(){
        Console.WriteLine("Första valet");
        Console.WriteLine("Tryck Enter för att återgå till menyn");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Move `public static void FirstChoice()` up by 3 lines so it's inside the class and not directly in the namespace.

Comment: Yes now it finally works! Thank you!!!